# Can I use some other class's function as a delegate?

Tags: c#

Say I have 2 classes, class A and class B. Class A creates an instance of Class B. Class A has a function that I would like to pass into a method from Class B.

```
class A {
  void Main(string[] args) {
    B classB=new B();

    DelegateCaller(new delFunction(classB.TheFunction());   // <-- Won't compile (method name expected)
    DelegateCaller(new delFunction(B.TheFunction());        // <-- Won't compile (object reference is req'd)
  }

  public delegate string delFunction();

  public DelegateCaller(delFunction func) {
    System.Console.WriteLine(func());
  }
}

class B {
  public string TheFunction() {
    return "I'm Printing!!!";
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if it a syntax issue or it's just something I can't do. Maybe I need to define the delegate in B, but reference it in A? What about B's **this** pointer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a syntax issue; get rid of the parentheses after `classB.TheFunction` - they indicate that you wish to *invoke* the method.

```
DelegateCaller(new delFunction(classB.TheFunction));
```

Do note that there is an implicit conversion available from a method-group, so you can just do:

```
DelegateCaller(classB.TheFunction);
```

Also note that creating your own delegate-type in this case is unnecessary; you could just use the in-built `Func<string>` type.

EDIT: As Darin Dimitrov points out, there is also the unrelated issue of calling an instance method as though it were a static method.

Comment: his code is far from compiling even with this. See my answer why.

Comment: If I could I'd give both you and Darin the check mark, but since you were first and have a lower rep, you're getting it.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
class A
{
    static void Main()
    {
        B classB = new B();
        DelegateCaller(classB.TheFunction);
    }

    public delegate string delFunction();

    public static void DelegateCaller(delFunction func) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(func());
    }
}

class B
{
    public string TheFunction()
    {
        return "I'm Printing!!!";
    }
}
```

Let me elaborate about the different changes I've made to your initial code:

1. `TheFunction` in class B needs to be public so that you can access it from class A
2. The `DelegateCaller` method in class A should be static and not necessarily return a value (declare it as void) if you want to call it from the static `Main` method.
3. The definition of the `delFunction` delegate should return a string.

Comment: I noticed the missing public after I posted (the real code is too big for example, I reduced it down). Same with the missing static. The real usage is not inside of Main. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take the parenthesis off the end of TheFunction. You want the method, not the result of a call to the method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture an instance method for usage in a general purpose fashion you should use `Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type,MethodInfo)`. This is nice as it allows you to create an "open delegate" meaning it isn't bound to an instance and can take any instance that is a `ClassB`. It makes reflection quite fast if you know the type information, as this method will perform much faster than the equivalent statement using `MethodInfo.Invoke`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DelegateCaller(new delFunction(B.TheFunction());
```

Should be

```
DelegateCaller(new delFunction(B.TheFunction);
```

To use classB.TheFunction  you would need to make TheFunction static.  You pass in the function with no parens.